# I need know How to add multiple middleware in Laravel controller but when first middleware is not checked check second middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, composer-php, middleware

Hi everyone I have an idea but I don't know how to do it

I hope someone can help me and thanks.

I want to add multiple middleware but if the first one is not checked, check the second.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth','auth:admin']); // // it work with "&&" but i want to convert it to "||" 
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't need both in this case?  auth:admin should also check if logged in before checking admin status

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fresh middleware and merge these two middlewares into that, and call new one.